# How to import Papaparse

Tags: javascript, import, svelte, vite, papaparse

I have a Svelte/Js/Vite app and need to import Papaparse. It's installed as `npm install papaparse` and is present in the `package.json`.

When I import it as `import * as Papa from "papaparse";`, methods are not visible in the IDE (i.e. `parse()`) and the following error is shown:

> error loading dynamically imported module. This could be due to syntax errors or importing non-existent modules. (see errors above)

When I import it as `import {Papa} from "papaparse";`, methods are visible in the IDE, but there s a message

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Papa'

and it anyway doesn't work in a browser with the same error.

What is the proper way to import and what is the reason for these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to import it this way since it's a default exported member:

```js
import Papa from "papaparse";

// the name does not really matter. You can name it whatever you want
// as you're basically saying:
// import { default as Papa } from "papaparse"

// So, you can do it like this too:
// import Mama from "papaparse";
```

If you'd like to learn more about why, I'd recommend reading this article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-modules-and-import-and-export-statements-in-javascript

Comment: It works but the IDE anyway doesn't see the method parse...

Comment: It seems that the library itself is not typed. Installing its types separately could help your idea have an idea. Try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/papaparse